# gacutil from MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, gacutil

in my MSBuild file (TFSBuild.proj since I am running Team Builds) the exec command=gacutil alwys fails with the following error:
 Failure initializing gacutil
my build machine is a W2K3 with Team Build 2010.

any ideas.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do a system-wide search for the following file: gacutil.exe.config

Then open the file in Notepad and check to see which version .NET Framework it references.    It may look like the following:

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <requiredRuntime version="v1.1.4322"  />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

For me, and probably for most PCs with .NET Frameworks which are more recent than Version 1.1, This config file will cause the message "Failure initializing gacutil".    The following config file will work better:

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <requiredRuntime safemode="true" imageVersion="v4.0.30319" version="v4.0.30319"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

I came to this answer with help from Nitya-MSFT.   See the following link, specifically the answer from Nitya-MSFT:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/49d4a656-40f1-4bb9-b1a7-da0f63557d0e/failure-initializing-gacutil

My customer's PC was previously a 32-bit machine running Windows 7 & .NET Framework 1.1.    Then, sometime recently, it was upgraded to have a 64-bit operating system running Windows 10 & .NET Framework 4.0.      However, the gacutil.exe was still running against an old config file, gacutil.exe.config, which was pointing to the old .NET Framework 1.1.      I used the XML supplied by Nitya-MSFT in order to create a new gacutile.exe.config.   Of course, I placed it into the folder alongside the gacutil.exe executable.     And my trouble went away!!    Much appreciation to Nitya-MSFT.

Comment: Instead of doing a systemwide search, I'd recommend first using `where gacutil` to determine where you're using the gacutil from, and modifying the gacutil.exe.config located beside it. This will be the gacutil you're using unless you're explicitly configured to use a different one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the .NET framework SDK installed?  I don't believe Gacutil is part of the standard .NET loadout.

Comment: yes it installed here:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\

Comment: Make sure that path is included in your path search.  Why do you want to GAC files in your build process?

Comment: yes the whole path is included...it is my requirement to gac from MSBuild

Comment: Ok, then.  The last thing I could think of is that the build service account doesn't have rights to add things to the global assembly cache.  Without any other specific error messages (like maybe eventlog), I'm at a loss.

Comment: Try running gacutil from a normal CMD.exe prompt ON that server AS the build agent.  That should give you exactly what the build server is seeing.

Even invoking by full path may not give gacutil.exe what it needs, I don't remember that tool, but a lot of the tools that run under the SDK command prompt require some other stuff